# How to detect component collision in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

First off, I'm new to asking stack overflow questions, so go easy on me guys.
I am trying to figure out how to detect collision of components; namely, a draggable component containing a button-circle component. Sadly, there appears to be zero information online regarding this. I'm thinking the draggable component may be able to handle some sort of radius tracking, which is computed when the user takes their finger off the screen, but hard tracking the radius would seem to be very resource intensive. I really need some ideas here guys. Relevant code is below.

## Draggable.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  PanResponder,
  Animated,
} from "react-native";

import CircleButton from 'react-native-circle-button';

export default class Draggable extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
      scale: new Animated.Value(1),
    };
  }



  //Function to handle animations and button pressing of bubbles.
  componentWillMount() {
    let finalx = 0;
    let finaly = 0;

    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => false,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return gestureState.dx <= finalx && gestureState.dy <= finaly;
      },

      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return gestureState.dx <= finalx && gestureState.dy <= finaly;
      },

      onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
        this.state.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
        this.finalx = gestureState.dx;
        this.finaly = gestureState.dy;
        Animated.spring(
          this.state.scale,
          { toValue: 1.1, friction: 3 }
        ).start();
      },

      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null, {dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y},
      ]),

      onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, vy}) => {
        this.state.pan.flattenOffset(); 
        Animated.spring(
          this.state.pan,
          { toValue: {x:0, y:0}},

          this.state.scale,
          { toValue: 1, friction: 3 }
        ).start();
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let { pan } = this.state;

    let rotate = '0deg';

    let [translateX, translateY] = [pan.x, pan.y];

    let moveableStyle = {transform: [{translateX}, {translateY}, {rotate}]};
    const panStyle = {
      transform: this.state.pan.getTranslateTransform()
    }
    return (
      <Animated.View
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[moveableStyle, panStyle]}>
          <CircleButton />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

## Homepage.js

```
<View style={styles.middleContainer}>
    { this.state.bubbles.map((item, key)=>(
        <Draggable key={key}> { item }</Draggable>)
    )}
</View>
```